# Как передать на письме содержание настенных табличек?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать предложение? 
**[...], и в поле зрения появилась стена с белой табличкой "Екатеринбург Выход в город".**
По идее, в такой табличке между названием города и словом "выход" нет точки, т.е. верхняя строчка - "Екатеринбург", строкой ниже - "Выход в город". Нужно ли ставить точку на письме? И нужно ли двоеточие перед кавычками?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вряд ли на этот счёт есть строгое правило. Стоит подобрать выход под себя. Самый бережный по отношению к содержанию вариант — поставить двоеточие и написать с новой строки в середине страницы текст таблички двумя строками. Более экономичный выход — обойтись знаком препинания "/", как делают, цитируя стихи. Либо допустить некоторые авторские вольности: "ЕКАТЕРИНБУРГ Выход в город", "Екатеринбург: выход 
 в город" — никто не предъявит за это претензий. Но я бы выбирал из первых двух вариантов. Строгих рекомендаций тут нет и быть не может.

Двоеточие перед содержанием таблички факультативно. Даже при передачи фраз без него, бывает, обходятся. Если бы выбор стоял за мной, я бы от двоеточия в случае таблички отказался.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что в данном случае содержание таблички нужно оформить в виде двух назывных предложений:

***[...], и в поле зрения появилась стена с белой табличкой "Екатеринбург. Выход в город".***

Так как надпись оформлена в одну строку, необходимо поставить знак между двумя синтаксическими единицами.

Ср.:*Осталась охрана лишь возле кабинета, на дверях которого ― золотистая металлическая табличка: «М.С. Горбачев, Президент Союза Советских Социалистических Республик».* [Борис Грищенко. Посторонний в Кремле (2004)] - пример из Национального корпуса РЯ.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, нужно писать максимально близко к оригиналу. В данном случае на табличке два предложения, там была бы точка, будь они написаны в одну строку.

**...стена с белой табличкой "Екатеринбург. Выход в город".**